# Programmatically Fling ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

Is there a way I can programatically perform a Fling on a listview? I know there is monkey that does all these things but that requires a computer connection with adb etc etc. I want to do it with my app on any phone, without monkey.

Thanks,
Faisal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fake it with an anim (i think accelerate_decelerate_interpolator can do the job).

Also it seems there is support for scrolling your view by your own:

```
public void scrollBy (int x, int y)
```

Move the scrolled position of your view. This will cause a call to onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int) and the view will be invalidated.

```
Parameters
x   the amount of pixels to scroll by horizontally
y   the amount of pixels to scroll by vertically
```

```
public void scrollTo (int x, int y)
```

Set the scrolled position of your view. This will cause a call to onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int) and the view will be invalidated.

```
Parameters
x   the x position to scroll to
y   the y position to scroll to
```

Comment: Hey Lucas, do you have a code snippet, I'm pretty confused.

Thanks,
Faisal

Comment: Hello, i added more info that will help you.

Comment: This does not work. It scrolls the view containing the listView, but not the actual listView... sorry... still looking.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to "smooth scroll" rather than jump to a position.

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

for `smoothScrollBy()` and `smoothScrollTo()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are referring to scrollview and the question was for a listview. Listview also has some neat features: smootScrollToPosition and smootScrollByOffset. However these are only available in api level 8 and 11 respectively. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

Answer (score 1):

```
private AnimationSet set;

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.pullbutton){
        artListview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(set == null){
            set = new AnimationSet(true);
            Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            animation.setDuration(100);
            set.addAnimation(animation);

            animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, 
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,             
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
            );
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            set.addAnimation(animation);
        }
        showPullDownSectionList();
    }

}


public void showPullDownSectionList() {
    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
    flipper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setLayoutAnim_slidedownfromtop(flipper);
}

public  void setLayoutAnim_slidedownfromtop(ViewFlipper flipper) {
    LayoutAnimationController controller =
        new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);
    flipper.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

}
```