# move screen from finger

Tags: android

move screen from finger in android just like a slider please give me a example .

thanks 
Ashish

Comment: you'll get more help if post some code you tried. otherwise people think that your not even trying.

Answer (score 1):

This is called fling for what you are looking for.
Answer is already given in stack over flow Here is the link.
[Programmatically Fling ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214956/programmatically-fling-listview-android)